# Edit files with SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm new to SharePoint and using SharePoint Foundation server 2010 to save files using client object model. The application will list the files in the server using MVC4 UI. To retreive the files and folders I use SharePoint 2010 client object model. I want to implement the Edit feature for the word and excel documents which is already available when we access SharePoint site directly through IE. Simply I just want to open the file and save changes to the server when we save it or close the program. Is it possible to do using client object model. I can open the file but not save the changes to the server. I google it to find a solution but yet not succeeded. If anybody knows how to do it please answer. Thanks in advance.

I just want to implement the following feature in my mvc4 application using client object model.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/323127

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the versioning in SharePoint so that they will update the file automatically for you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956106.aspx